# Common elements in finite subfields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be subfields of finite field $F$ consisting  of $2^9$ and $2^6$ elements respectively. Then what is  total number of elements in $F_1$ and $F_2$?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* The lattice of subfields of a finite field of order $p^n$ is isomorphic to the lattice of divisors of $n$.